# How to correctly use $vuetify.goTo with v-lazy components?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load few components into my website using Vue2 and Vuetify. Each component takes about one screen size on my desktop browser and `vuetify.goTo` works perfectly fine there.

Problem occurs when I try to test it on my mobile. On a first click I'm taken to previous element. Second click (when elements are loaded) leads to right place. I expected that my function will load all previous components and on desktop it seems to work fine. Could you please help me find solution to this issue?

On a mobile second element gets bigger about 150-200vh - *maybe it causes troubles?* - it's a gallery similar to this [from docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images/#grid)), but I have tried to modify `min-height` of `v-lazy` with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-btn v-for="item in items" :key="item.component" @click="goToItem(item.component)">
        {{ item.component }}
      </v-btn>

        <v-lazy v-for="item in items" :key="item.component" :id="item.component" v-model="item.isActive"
          :options="{ threshold: .9 }" :min-height="item.component === 'contact' ? '300' : '50vh'">
          <v-componenet :is="item.component" />
        </v-lazy>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Intro from '@/components/Intro';
import Contact from '@/components/Contact';
import Projects from '@/components/Projects';
import Trainings from '@/components/Trainings';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Contact,
    Intro,
    Projects,
    Trainings,
  },
  data: () => ({
    items: [{component: 'intro',isActive: false,},{component: 'projects',isActive: false,},{component: 'trainings',isActive: false,},{component: 'contact',isActive: false,},],
  }),
  methods: {
    goToItem(destination) {
      for (const item of this.items) {
        item.isActive = true
        if (item.component === destination) {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$vuetify.goTo('#' + item.component)
          })
          return
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VLazy/VLazy.ts

The height is definetly an issue. If you look at the source-code of `v-lazy`, the `active` is just enabling the IntersectionObserver. The `isIntersecting` is false though, because the component is not in the view. So `isActive` is also false. Maybe have a look at the devtools an the `isActive` state of the component.

A small reproduction would be ns here.